# How to diagnose missing disk space?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I had a program installed: "Digital Lifeboat", which was a distributed backup service. The company closed up last year so I uninstalled the application.

After uninstall, it left behind some folders on almost all of my partitions. Some folders were empty or only contained other empty folders so I removed them.

One folder on most partitions (named "LifeboatStorage") had ownership settings that didn't allow me to delete (or even open) them. I thought I would eventually get rid of them, but I didn't pay much attention to them since then.

Recently, I tried to save a small file on one of the partitions and I got an error that there wasn't enough disk space. I looked at the properties of the partition (H:), and it said I had about 8GB of space available.

I started to transfer some files from that partition to another, to free up some space, and I found the same issue on another partition (G:). About 8GB of space available, but unable to store some small files.

I thought, how could the drives have 8GB of space available yet be unable to store some small text files. I ran "Chkdsk" (and "Chkdsk /f") on the drives, which both came up clean, on both drives.

Then it came to me that it could be related to the "LifeboatStorage" folder. So, I took ownership, and checked the properties of the folder and found that it contained 8GB of files, in many folders (on each drive). The exact byte count of this space, and the missing space were not exactly the same, but quite close. Considering the space taken up by the folders, it might be exact.

Here is a screenshot of the properties of the drive and folder on G:
[image: Properties of drive and folder on G:]

And the properties of the drive and folder on H:
[image: Properties of drive and folder on H:]

I haven't deleted the folders/files yet. I wanted to do some analysis first because once I delete them, depending on what happens, I might loose all the information about what happened.

So, I suppose there are a few possibilities when I delete these folders:
  1. The reported drive free space will remain at 8GB, but I will actually have 8GB of free space.
  2. The reported drive free space will show 16GB, but I will actually have 8GB of free space.
  3. Some other combination of #1 and #2.

If it turns out to be #1, it would seen that "Digital Lifeboat" was responsible for the discrepancy, but it opens the question of: How could it consume the space but not be shown in the drive usage/free space report?

If it turns out to be #2, then it is possible (but still not definite) that the problem is unrelated to "Digital Lifeboat".

My concern is that there was some sort of "hack" to the partition table or the directory that will not be undone by simply deleting the files.

Is anyone familiar with this issue? What can I do to diagnose this before (or after) I delete the files.

---

My intent no matter what, is definitely to delete these files. As I said before, my concern is over the fact that in the current state, it appears that the free space is being misreported. If I just blindly delete the files, I may still be blocked from using that free space. Of course, I won't know until I try. But I think I need to do some investigating before I do that in case deleting the files makes it more difficult to diagnose the problem.

It seems obvious to me that these files and folders were not created in the "usual" ways since doing so would have been reflected in the standard drive space usage information.

I was hoping that either someone else had gone through this already (with this application) and could provide some insight, or if there was any advice on where to look for what might cause the free space to be misreported.

In the end, it may be that my only choice is to just delete the files. If that's the case, I have no problem giving that a try and reporting what I find.

Comment: There are dozens of tools that will report how your disk space is being used.  Which utilities have you used?  There are numerous questions which even suggest some of these tools. If you no longer need those folders, take ownership of the folder with an Administrator user, and delete the folders.

Comment: If you no longer require the data, why not just delete it? At the very least it's going to answer your questions pretty quickly. Without seeing what effect deleting the data has, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: https://windirstat.info/

Answer (score 1):

When you open Explorer and select properties, Windows reads the free space from the NTFS bitmap metafile. Selecting all files/folders in explorer and showing properties, scan all files/folders. But Windows skips here hidden files/folders and folders where your current user doesn't have read permissions (System Volume Information folder for example).

You should use [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) (run it as admin) to see which folders take most space:

[image: TreeSizeFree]